# Can I ask similar type of questions frequently?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Am I allowed to ask similar type of questions but not same questions frequently?

Consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794670/confusion-in-identification-of-proposition) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794620/which-of-the-following-are-propositions) for example.

Comment: You should treat the priviledge of asking questions here as a limited resource.
The system will automatically limit how much questions you can ask each day (6?) and each month (50?). If you ask too many similar questions at too short a span of time, you may run into the danger that people get annoyed and downvote your questions. If your attract too many downvotes, the system will issue a question ban. You are allowed to ask similar questions but you should show some self-restraint....

Comment: If questions resemble one another too closely, one can correctly be closed as a duplicate of an earlier post.  E.g., Someone asks:  What is the derivative of $f(x)= 3x^2 + 1$.  Second question: What is the derivative of $f(x) = 2x^3 -3$.  The two questions are, for all intent and purposes, duplicates.  Learning how to do one should be enough to do the other.  I am glad you asked this question.  As achille hui suggests, sometimes you can ask a similar question to what you've asked; just try to make clear how the question differs from the first.  And please do so carefully.

Comment: I would recommend asking one question, and then studying the answers. If your questions are similar enough, some serious study of the answer to one of them might enable you to work out the others on your own. Even if it doesn't, it might enable you to sharpen your question by showing you just exactly where you need help.

Comment: Our stated mission is to help *students of mathematics* at all levels to *learn*.  Of course we will be concerned, if you ask similar Questions again and again, that our efforts to help you learn the material are not working.

Answer (score 3):

The challenge with these two questions is that they are missing key info. What class are you in? What book are you using? **What is the definition of proposition from the class, notes, or book?**

It might seem that there would be a single definition of "proposition" that everyone accepts, but that isn't so. For a brief intro, see [Propositions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/) in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

In mathematical logic, we move relatively quickly past the idea of natural-language propositions, after which we look only at formal languages in which there is a more objective definition of a "proposition" as a sentence in a formal language.  The real interest in natural language propositions is in philosophical logic and in applications of logic to non-mathematical areas.

So natural "propositions" tend to be covered only in the very beginning of an introductory logic course.   And, because they are natural language, it can be difficult to tell if they are intended to be propositions - this is where the emphasis provided by the definition in each course is important.

How can the questions be improved? First, read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).  Don't assume that the people on this site have access to your course materials.  There are probably other examples that you have been given in the notes, book, or lecture - mention those in the question.

After you ask a question, as several commenters have mentioned, read and think about the answers and comments before asking a similar question.  A follow up question is likely to be better received here if it shows that you have taken something from the previous answers and are now asking a more refined or specific question.